# What can you say about a series with terms equal to zero after the $n$-th term?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series that converges and that has the terms equal to zero after the $n$-th element. What can you say about the sum of the absolute values?

Thanks!

Comment: That it's the (convergent) sum of of finitely many nonnegative numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a_n=0$ for all $n\geq N$ then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|=\sum_{n=1}^N|a_n|<\infty.$$
So the series converges.